# Ubuntu 14.04 audio not working for headphone or speakers. Red light next to headphone jack

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, sound

I'm experiencing problems with my audio on my Ubuntu 14.04 distribution. Recently, the audio has stopped working for both my headphones and speakers. I have a dual-boot machine and audio is fine on the other machine. I also noticed a mysterious red led light illuminating from what appears to be the microphone jack. Any help to solve this problem would be very appreciated.

My machine is a Lenovo y50-70.

UPDATE: Audio seems to work on headphone jack and light goes away. However, when I unplug it the red light reappears and no sound is present. Even when I plug it back in the sound does not resume.